# modify show UI of a registered taxonomy

Tags: plugin-development, custom-taxonomy, theme-development

As you you know the `'show_ui'` Boolean option in taking care of rendering or not rending the Taxonomy Menu on UI on registering  ataxonomy.

```
function custom_taxonomy() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                       => 'Taxonomies',
        'singular_name'              => 'Taxonomy',
        'menu_name'                  => 'Taxonomy',
        'all_items'                  => 'All Items',
        'parent_item'                => 'Parent Item',
        'parent_item_colon'          => 'Parent Item:',
        'new_item_name'              => 'New Item Name',
        'add_new_item'               => 'Add New Item',
        'edit_item'                  => 'Edit Item',
        'update_item'                => 'Update Item',
        'view_item'                  => 'View Item',
        'separate_items_with_commas' => 'Separate items with commas',
        'add_or_remove_items'        => 'Add or remove items',
        'choose_from_most_used'      => 'Choose from the most used',
        'popular_items'              => 'Popular Items',
        'search_items'               => 'Search Items',
        'not_found'                  => 'Not Found',
        'no_terms'                   => 'No items',
        'items_list'                 => 'Items list',
        'items_list_navigation'      => 'Items list navigation',
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'                     => $labels,
        'hierarchical'               => false,
        'public'                     => true,
        'show_ui'                    => true,
        'show_admin_column'          => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
        'show_tagcloud'              => true,
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'taxonomy', array( 'post' ), $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_taxonomy', 0 );
```

Is there any way to modify this option after registering the taxonomy? like any hook or filter to toggle the Boolean in `functions.php`

Answer (score 1):

you can use this filter which is used inside `register_taxonomy`

```
add_filter("register_taxonomy_args", function ($register_taxonomy_args, $name, $object_type) {


    if ("taxonomy" === $name) {

        $register_taxonomy_args["show_ui"] = FALSE;

    }


    return $register_taxonomy_args;

}, 10, 3);
```